# How can I output the names of rows which are NA in a given column in R?

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I am working with panel data, and I've found out that I have 16 NAs in a column I am interested by typing:

```
sum(is.na(df$X1995))
[1] 16
```

Now I want to know which rows had missing values for this year. Which rows had these 16 NAs?

I tried this, but it returns NULL:

```
rownames(which(is.na(df$X1995)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `row.names` needs to be of some object.  The `which(is.na` returns a numeric index and it is not an object having the row names attribute

```
row.names(df)[which(is.na(df$X1995))]
```

Wrapping with `which` is also not needed as the `is.na` returns a logical vector which can be used to subset the rownames

```
row.names(df)[is.na(df$X1995)]
```

If the rownames are just sequence values, the `which` itself is enough

```
which(is.na(df$X1995))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62107331/12158757) has explained the reason in details.

Below is another option maybe work for you as well, where `subset` sorts out those rows with `NA` and then you can read the row names:

```
row.names(subset(df,is.na(X1995)))
```